# Gaps on Google Map

Tags: maps

Can anyone help me about this issue please ?

As it works fine on local, I'm wondering if this only happens on live ?

And I just have jquery and jquery cookie js files attached to this page.

Thanks,

[image: Gaps on Google map?]

Comment: What CSS is set on this page?

Comment: Nothing more than margin: 0 auto; and width: 80%; and there is no error or warning at Chrome developer tools